# how to get the value in the input box and pass to another webpage for display?

Tags: php, post, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 doctrine. I have a project that when the user inputs his/her information, its value(information) should pass on another webpage and display it. I'm planning to use 'post method' to get its value and display it to another webpage. Since I'm using symfony, It's too difficult to get its value.

Is there another way to get the value and display it to another webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use form for it.

For example

1. Render form in  **searchSuccess.php** (or you  can manually made form without rendering)

`<form method="post`" action="`<?php echo url_for('search') ?>`"  >

```
     <?php echo $form['search']->renderRow() ?> 


     <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('search')?>" />                

 </form>
```

1. In action :

   public function executeResult(sfWebRequest $request)
     {

   ```
   $this->search_query=$request->getParameter('search');
   ```

   }
2. In **resultSuccess.php** (page  where you want display info)

   echo $search_query